# Windows 10 Development: How to check if the current page is a specific page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10

I want to check if the current page that the user is on/viewing is a specific page - MainPage. If the user is on MainPage, I want to ensure pressing the back button does not navigate to the previous page but exit the application instead. Is there anyway to check what is the page the user is on currently?

Or is there any better way to achieve what I want to achieve: to ensure pressing the back button on MainPage does not navigate to previous page but exit the application instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `NavigationEventArgs.SourcePageType` in the navigation methods. It will return the type of the current page.

**NOTE**

Until there is entry in the backstack the back button will navigate to that entry (page). If the backstack is empty pressing backbutton will close the app. In my apps when the users presses the home button (navigating to mainpage), I always remove everything from the backstack except for the MainPage, and this ensures that pressing back button on MainPage will always exit.

**EDIT** 
Code that I use to go back to MainPage (The pro for this solution is that this way the navigation events of the pages in the backstack won't be called, because they are removed. If they weren't removed their navigation events would be called while traversing through the backstack, which could cause unexpected behavior.):

```
private void goHome() {

        var bs = Frame.BackStack.Where(b => b.SourcePageType.Name == "MainPage").FirstOrDefault();

        if (bs != null)
        {
            Frame.BackStack.Clear();
            Frame.BackStack.Add(bs);
        }

        this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for that:

Put this in App.xaml.cs at end of OnLaunched method,

```
// Register a handler for BackRequested events and set the
// visibility of the Back button
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
            rootFrame.CanGoBack ?
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
```

And write this method,

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
    //you can check for this here rootFrame.BackStack[rootFrame.BackStack.Count-1].SourcePageType.Name

}
```

Also you can check for pages and control the visibility of back button in Desktop apps like this,

```
private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Each time a navigation event occurs, update the Back button's visibility
        Frame rootFrame = (Frame)sender;
        if (rootFrame.BackStack != null && rootFrame.BackStack.Count == 1)
        {
            // take care in page names
            if (rootFrame.BackStack[0].SourcePageType.Name == "MainPage"
                || rootFrame.BackStack[0].SourcePageType.Name == "AnyOtherPage")
            {
                rootFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
            ((Frame)sender).CanGoBack ?
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
            AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
```